# Split large files into files with .001 .002 (and so on) extension in CentOS via Terminal

Tags: linux, ssh, centos

How to split large files into parts with .001 .002 (and so on) extension in CentOS via SSH Terminal (using Putty)?

For example, if I have a large file - **LargeFile.iso**, then how can I be able to split it into files like **LargeFile.iso.001**, **LargeFile.iso.002**, **LargeFile.iso.003**, **LargeFile.iso.004**.... and so on till **LargeFile.iso.xxx** (where **xxx** is the last part)?

Answer (score 5):

Split is your friend
with options:

```
-d --numeric-suffix  for numerical suffixes
-a -- suffix-lenght  for suffix lenght
```

Give a look at

```
split --help
```

in terminal

Answer (score 0):

The best way might be a short bash script along the lines of

```
#!/bin/bash

BS=1024
SEGMENT=100000

LEN=$(ls -l | awk '{ print $5; }')
BL=$(($LEN/$BS))
S=0
I=1
while test "$BL" -le "$S"; do
  dd if="$1" of="$1."$(printf '%03d' $I) bs="$BS" skip="$S" count="$SEGMENT" 2>/dev/null
  S=$(($s+$SEGMENT))
  I=$(($I+1))
done
```